# AWS Timestream "Not equal" comparison throws error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-timestream

I have a query where I want to fetch all data where "completed" field is not equal to 0, but it throws an error. I dont get it why as their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/comparison-operators.html) supports these comparisons.

```
$result = $query_client->query([
    'MaxRows' => 1,
    'QueryString' => 'SELECT field1, field2, completed, date 
FROM "db"."table"
WHERE completed != 0  // Tried as "0" as well, doesnt work
ORDER BY date DESC',
]);
```

Error:

> com.amazonaws.timestream.v20181101.query#ValidationException,
> '<>' cannot be applied to varchar, integer"

Comment: Try `NOT LIKE "0"`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller now it says:  Pattern for LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

```
   $result = $query_client->query([
     'MaxRows' => 1,
     'QueryString' => 'SELECT field1, field2, completed, date 
      FROM \"db\".\"table\"
      WHERE completed =  '" . 0 . "'
      ORDER BY date DESC',
   ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).